# "Inheritor of the ResourceDictionary is expected" - What does this error mean

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

In App.xaml I have the following code:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="FJW.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/F4.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/F3.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/F2.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/F0.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/F1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/Palm.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/Key.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Visual Studio is finding error in strings `<ResourceDictionary Source="themes/...xaml"/>`
- raising the following error message: *Inheritor of the ResourceDictionary is expected.*

But the project is getting compiled properly and is working right. What does the error message mean? Maybe it is a bug of this beta Silverlight version? Or is it my error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hm. It was a BuildAction problem.

I set up BuildAction property for xamls as Resource. And when I changed this property back to Page - erorrs are vanished.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx contains some relevant details re: the BuildAction of resource dictionary files.

Comment: I changed this to "Page" but it still shows me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something inside one those .xaml files that's getting you?  I copied your code into a new project and didn't see any error messages in either Visual Studio or Expression Blend.

[alt text http://www.smips.com/brad/stackoverflow/so-109.jpg](http://www.smips.com/brad/stackoverflow/so-109.jpg)

Comment: I think it can't. Becouse when I leave only one xaml in themes folder - there were not errors.